# How to make sure numbers with decimals contain exactly two decimals in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

This question concerns programming in VBA

Data type I am using is `Double`, because data type `Decimal` is not recognized by the compiler. This is a contributing issue.

```
Private Number1 as Double
Number1 = (read from a data source which contains 2 decimals)
Number1 = 0.15 * Number1 '#client needs to have a 0.15 multiplier for Number1. This multiplication causes number format problems.
Number1 = Round(Number1, 2)
Number1 = formatNumber(Number1, 2)
```

Does not work. There are still much more than only 2 decimals remaining in Number1 in the output.

Is there an easy pre-built library solution to this problem? Or should I make a custom method to format the number? What would be a recommended way to build that custom method?

Comment: Do you want to truncate the number at 2 decimal places or round it to 2 decimal places? 12.347 could be 12.34 or 12.35.

Comment: I want to round it to 2 decimal places into the output. 

If rounding is not feasibly possible, then I can accept truncate as a secondary option.

Comment: The `CCur` Type Conversion Function will give you 4 decimal places (rounded off high or low at the 4th) but I don't know of any that will give you 2.

Comment: You can't use directly `Decimal`, but you can have a `Decimal`  stored into a Variant using `CDec`.

Comment: What you can do is, force the range where you store your number in to only show 2 decimals like so: Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.00"

Answer (score 1):

*In examples below you can see that only 2 decimals remaining in `Number1` after `round()` function, or in another similar functions*

```
Sub test()
    Dim Number1 As Double
    Dim FX As Object: Set FX = WorksheetFunction

    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236:                                      Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.1854
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = Round(Number1, 2):         Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.19
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = FX.Round(Number1, 2):      Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.19
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = FX.RoundUp(Number1, 2):    Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.19
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = FX.RoundDown(Number1, 2):  Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.18
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = FX.Ceiling(Number1, 0.01): Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.19
    Number1 = 0.15 * 1.236: Number1 = FX.Floor(Number1, 0.01):   Debug.Print Number1 'return 0.18
End Sub
```

*test*

[image]

---

*So your code should work's fine, problem must be elsewhere (for instance in cell format).*

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that the code originally posted does work to 2 decimal places. I think the data is being converted elsewhere so doubt if any function as such will do the job. Hard to say without the code... maybe.

Comment: I think you are right, my examples also show that all is ok with code, and problem must be elsewhere (for instance in cell format). I will update my post to provide more undestandable repesentation that all is ok with variable

Answer (score 0):

If you *need* to use a decimal type, you can declare as a variant and convert.

```
Dim d As Variant
d = CDec(3.14)
```

At a guess though, it looks to me though, your code snippet isn't at fault here....maybe..

It looks to me that after this function is called, you're converting from a double to something else which is where you need to concentrate your efforts - not inside this function.